# Recommended SQL Version for Mid-Level Web Application

Tags: sql-server, database, express

**Hi Guys,** 
I am going to start one new project as a freelancer. I want help to decide which version of SQL Server should I use. Either Sql Server 2012 Express Edition or Sql Server 2014 Developer Edition.

I can purchase Developer Edition as it is not costly.

The problem is Express edition don't have SQL Job Agent and on [Microsoft Website](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msin/en_GB/pdp/SQL-Server-2014-Developer-Edition/productID.304785800) it is said that Developer Edition cannot be used on production.

**Please help me deciding what should I prefer.**

Comment: If you can't use developer on production, then use the express version, of course.

Comment: Zohar, he says he needs Sql server agent. Besides, I'm pretty sure this isn't a programming question.

Comment: Yes guys, if you suggest me to use Express edition then I would like to get suggestion from you regarding what will be the alternative I can use for Sql Job Agent. Or you can suggest me any way that I can use to put Developer edition on production

Comment: What specifically do you need about the agent?  in theory most basic items can automation tasks can be controlled through command line and powershell through windows task scheduler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developer Edition can't be used in production, so that's a non-starter. That leaves you with a) Express, or b) springing for a better licence and buying Web edition. It really depends on what you want to use the agent for, if its just backups there are other tools available, but you will more than likely want to perform other maintenance tasks (history cleanup, reorganizing indexes etc)

Have you considered Windows Azure? You could set up a [SQL Azure Database](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/sql-database/) instance, which you could combine with [Azure Automation](https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/06/26/azure-automation-your-sql-agent-in-the-cloud/) to perform your jobs?